# "object-fit" is ignored when using "translate3d"

Tags: css, css-transitions

When using "object-fit:cover" and making a animation by using "translate3d" to this objec (img), then its object-fit-property (which is set to "cover) is totally ignored.

How can I avoid this?

Using "translate3d" to parent of object, does not help, because then, translate3d is animated on parent - which is not what I want. I can achieve my effect with object-position, but I want to use translate3d, if I can. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Can you show a sample demo. I tried a sample and it doesn't seem to be having any problem in Chrome.

Comment: ok, solved it. I have used translate3d to change the position within the image itself. this does not work. Now,  I use object-position. Now It works..